# how to choose which heroku app to deploy to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a heroku app, that's like the default, but I want to deploy to another heroku app. So I created another heroku app, but how do I push to that new app? The info still shows the old app. Is there a way I can select the new app to push to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using git you can start by creating a new remote for your repo:

```
git remote add second-heroku-app git@heroku.com:appname.git
```

Replace second-heroku-app with whatever you want and appname with the name of your new app.

Then you can push from the current branch you are working on to your new heroku app like this:

```
git push second-heroku-app
```

Comment: Just a note - you should add the (default) branch in the end - `git push second-heroku-app`.